# TypeScript recursive conditional mapped types

Tags: typescript

I need to test each value of multiple `HTMLInputElement`s using a/some test function(s), and auto-generate a nested list of checkboxes for each, with the conditions which are expressed as `Conditions` below:

```
type TestFunction = (value: string) => boolean
type TestFunctionObject = { [description: string]: Conditions }
type Conditions = TestFunction | TestFunctionObject
```

So, for example, if I have:

```
const conds1: Conditions = {
  "Consists of alphanumerics": /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test
}
```

I get a checkbox labeled as "Consists of alphanumerics". And if:

```
const conds2: Conditions = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test
```

I don't want a checkbox but just validate with that.

Auto-generating is done without any problem. Then, I wrote a type which represents validity of each `TestFunction`:

```
type Validity<C extends Conditions> = C extends TestFunction
  ? boolean
  : { [K in keyof C]: Validity<C[K]> }
```

Now I got an error from TS on `C[K]`; [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20TestFunction%20%3D%20(value%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%0D%0Atype%20TestFunctionObject%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bdescription%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Conditions%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Conditions%20%3D%20TestFunction%20%7C%20TestFunctionObject%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Validity%3CC%20extends%20Conditions%3E%20%3D%20C%20extends%20TestFunction%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20C%5D%3A%20Validity%3CC%5BK%5D%3E%20%7D%0D%0A). It says `Type 'Conditions[K]' is not assignable to type 'TestFunctionObject'`. Type conditioning doesn't seem to narrow `Conditions` to just `TestFunctionObject`.

How can I get it to work?

**Addition for [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53473772/6708445)**: [Playground with examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20TestFunction%20=%20(value:%20string)%20=%3E%20boolean%0D%0Atype%20TestFunctionObject%20=%20%7B%20[description:%20string]:%20Conditions%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Conditions%20=%20TestFunction%20%7C%20TestFunctionObject%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Validity%3CC%20extends%20Conditions%3E%20=%20C%20extends%20TestFunctionObject%0D%0A%20%20?%20%7B%20[K%20in%20keyof%20C]:%20Validity%3CC[K]%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20:%20boolean%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20conds1%20=%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22Consists%20of%20alphanumerics%22:%20/%5E[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20conds2%20=%20/%5E[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20conds3%20=%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22Include%20at%20least%22:%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221%20basic%20Latin%20small%20letter%22:%20/(?=.*[a-z])./.test,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221%20basic%20Latin%20capital%20letter%22:%20/(?=.*[A-Z])./.test,%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20validity1:%20Validity%3Ctypeof%20conds1%3E%0D%0A//%20const%20validity1:%20%7B%20%22Consists%20of%20alphanumerics%22:%20boolean;%20%7D%0D%0A//%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20validity2:%20Validity%3Ctypeof%20conds2%3E%0D%0A//%20const%20validity2:%20boolean%0D%0A//%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20validity3:%20Validity%3Ctypeof%20conds3%3E%0D%0A//%20const%20validity3:%20%7B%20%22Include%20at%20least%22:%20any;%20%7D%0D%0A//%20Not%20OK%0D%0A)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the compiler does a lot of narrowing within the else clause of conditional types (after `:`)  the way it does with values via control flow analysis.  So while it's obvious to you that in the conditional type `C extends TestFunction`, the `C` in the else clause should extend `TestFunctionObject`, the compiler doesn't realize it.

But the compiler *does* do narrowing within the then clause (between `?` and `:`), so the easiest fix for this is to add another conditional type:

```
type Validity<C extends Conditions> = C extends TestFunction ? boolean
  : C extends TestFunctionObject ? { [K in keyof C]: Validity<C[K]> } : never
```

Note that the last conditional type has `never` as the else clause.  That's a common idiom with conditional types; sometimes you know the else clause cannot be reached; and in the absence of an [invalid type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689), the `never` type is a good alternative.

Or, since you weren't doing much with the then clause to begin with, flip the clauses of your original check:

```
type Validity<C extends Conditions> = C extends TestFunctionObject ?
  { [K in keyof C]: Validity<C[K]> } : boolean
```

Either should work.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the existence of narrowing in the `true` branch (and not the false branch) is what Anders is implying when he writes, "... references to `T` within `X` have an additional type parameter constraint `U`." Is that your interpretation of that sentence too? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316 I haven't seen this behavior documented anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I see the same line in the ["what's new" description of conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) but it's buried within the distributive conditional type section.

Comment: Wow, I'd been seeing a cheatsheet from its back!  Thanks, the error disappears. But actually it doesn't seem to work recursively. Added a playground. Is this a different problem?

Comment: That problem is just with how the type is displayed via IntelliSense, not with the actual type.  See [Microsoft/TypeScript#23897](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23897) for the display bug.  Note that in your Playground example, `validity3["Include at least"]["1 basic Latin capital letter"]` is of type `boolean` but `validity3["Include at least"].rando` is a compiler error (with `--noImplicitAny` turned on)